# How can I prevent vite from creating a .vite folder in the directory where I start it to host

Tags: vite

I use a global installation of vite so that I can host any folder I work on. When I called

```
vite
```

with version 3.1.6, this created an empty ".vite" folder. Even after stopping the process, that folder remained. With version 4.3.7 it got worse, now it creates a folder with a file

```
.\.vite\deps_temp_651f8552\package.json
```

where package.json holds

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

To clarify, I have no package.json in that folder. If I create such file, then vite creates a node_modules folder. So whatever I do vite creates folders I all do not want.

Any advice why vite creates those files and folders and how to avoid that?